# Performing Trigonometry in Javascript

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

How do I perform the following math problem in Javascript:

```
Tan(x) = 450/120;
x      = 75;
// In my calculator I use tan^-1(450/120) to find the answer
// How do I perform tan^-1 in javascript???
```

My javascript code is outputting incorrect results:

```
var x = Math.atan(450/120);
alert(x); // says x = 1.3101939350475555

// Maybe I am meant to do any of the following...
var x = Math.atan(450/120) * (Math.PI/2); // still wrong answer
var x = Math.tan(450/120);  // still wrong answer
```

Comment: Is your calculator in degrees mode? Real men use radians.

Comment: In all seriousness, one full revolution around a unit circle is an arc with the distance of 2Pi, which not coincidentally is the measurement of that angle in radians. Understanding that, and the relationship of other trigonomic functions to the unit circle, will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var x = Math.atan(450/120);
```

Gives the answer 75 degrees in radians, which is: 1.3101939350475555

To get the correct answer just convert to degrees:

```
var x = Math.atan(450/120) * (180/Math.PI);
alert(x); // says x is 75.06858282186245
```